# Error in if (N <= 0) NULL else seq(N) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, time-series, arima

```
maxP <- 2       
maxQ <- 2
AIC  <- matrix(0,nrow=maxP,ncol=maxQ)
BIC  <- matrix(0,nrow=maxP,ncol=maxQ)
HQC  <- matrix(0,nrow=maxP,ncol=maxQ)

# Save all information criteria
 for (p in 0:maxP){
  for(q in 0:maxQ){
     if (p>0) {ARLags <- 1:p} 
    else {ARLags <- 0}

    if (q>0) {MALags <- 1:q} 
    else{MALags <- 0}

    # Estimate the model
    CPI_fit <- arma(CPI, order(ARLags, MALags, include.intercept = TRUE)
    # Save the criteria in a P x Q matrix
    AIC[p+1, q+1] <- CPI_fit$aic
    BIC[p+1, q+1] <- CPI_fit$bic
  }
}

AIC
BIC
```

I'm trying to make an automatic procedure to select the model specification of an ARMA model, but I'm always getting this Error message:

```
Error in if (N <= 0) NULL else seq(N) : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What does it mean, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Can you include a piece of your `CPI` variable so it can be reproduced?

Comment: `order(ARLags, MALags, include.intercept = TRUE)` returns a vector of length 1 but `arma` expects the formal `order` to be of length 2.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d0kSv7mrqoxzfWry4G-cuWAlCYpMUZ-Ya0DFYu0N45s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try `CPI_fit <- arma(CPI, order = c(p,q), include.intercept = TRUE)`

Comment: Do you understand what `order` does? It is a function that returns the **order** of the input, i.e. for the input `c(1,3,2,5)` it returns the order in which the input comes in, in ascending order: `order(c(1,3,2,5)) = c(1,3,2,4)`. The function `tseries::arma` expects  the formal argument `order` to be a vector of length **two** where the first element is the AR part and the second element is the MA part of the ARMA model.

Comment: @YannickSchwarz Which package does your use of `arma` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using `tseries::arma`.

---

The problem lies in the call

```
arma(CPI, order(ARLags, MALags), include.intercept = TRUE)
```

You can find what calls the error by calling `traceback()`. This gives us a clue to the error:

```
2: seqN(order[2])
1: arma(CPI, order(ARLags, MALags), include.intercept = TRUE)
```

The second formal of `arma` is `order` which you have supplied with `order(ARLags, MALags)`. This means that for the function call we have

```
order = order(ARLags, MALags)
```

From the [description](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/order.html) of the **function** `order` used above:

> `order` returns a permutation which rearranges its **first** argument into ascending or descending order, breaking ties by further arguments. `sort.list` is the same, using only one argument.

(Emphasis mine) This permutation is used to sort data and is a vector of the same length as the input.  Meanwhile, the formal in `tseries::arma`, [according to the help page:](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tseries/versions/0.10-42/topics/arma)

> `order`     a two dimensional integer vector giving the orders of the model to fit. `order[1]` corresponds to the AR part and `order[2]` to the MA part.

And that is the conflict. `arma` expects a **two-dimensional integer vector** but is supplied a **one-dimensional vector** since for `p = 0` then `ARlags = 0` and `order(0) = 1`.

---

What you want to supply `arma` with is `order = c(p,q)` - the max lag terms in the AR and MA parts. Try this

```
CPI_fit <- arma(CPI, c(p, q), include.intercept = TRUE)
```

Comment: ``for (p in 0:maxP){
  for(q in 0:maxQ){
    if (p>0) {ARLags <- 1:p} # or just p?
    else {ARLags <- 0}
    
    if (q>0) {MALags <- 1:q} # or just q?
    else{MALags <- 0}
    
    # Estimate the model
    CPI_fit <- arma(CPI, order=c(ARLags, MALags), include.intercept = TRUE)
    # Save the criteria in a P x Q matrix
    AIC[p+1, q+1] <- CPI_fit$aic
    BIC[p+1, q+1] <- CPI_fit$bic
  }
}``

Comment: now it gives me the error: `Error in AIC[p + 1, q + 1] <- CPI_fit$aic : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: You changed the question so my answer is no longer applicable and either I should delete my answer or you should undo the change in your question (and possibly ask a new question I guess). The new code does not produce the error in the bottom of your question and the problem is now that the output of `arma` does not contain a list element called `aic`.

Comment: you are right. I changed it back to the original question. I changed also the code with your 'summary(CPI_fit)$aic', but it still I get an error message: `Error in optim(coef, err, gr = NULL, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters`